# Fake proof regarding continuity.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, fake-proofs

[image]
So to my understanding the fallacy in this argument is that it's circular. Since he didn't declare an ϵ at the beginning of the proof, his choice of ϵ is dependant on δ, which in turn is dependant on ϵ. We were taught to always begin our proofs with "Let ϵ>0 ... ", or "We choose ϵ=[blank/fill in later]>0 ... " and the fact that he doesn't raised my suspicion. But I can't TRULY point out his mistake, and my thought regarding the fallacy is purely intuitive, and the fact that everything else looks fine really makes me wonder if there is something that I am missing..

Comment: The "proof" is sly in that it doesn't say what $\epsilon_0$ is when it is first brought up, making it seem like we have an implicit "for all $\epsilon_0$...". But we haven't fixed such an $\epsilon_0$ yet, and if we had, it certainly doesn't necessarily need to be the number called "$\epsilon_0$" which is introduced after $\delta_1$ has already been defined (in terms of $\epsilon_0$, as you noticed). So the issue really comes down to omitting details to make the following conflation of (potentially different) $\epsilon_0$'s less noticeable.

Comment: hey again :)  I'm also trying to figure out what is the problem. I actually think that the choice of epsilon is ok, but take a look at student A definition of $\delta_{1}$. before "(surly, there exists such a delta)". note that there is an option which n+$\delta_{1}$ in smaller then $x_{1}+\delta$.

Comment: I think it is used to throw us off, since such a delta truly must exist haha. :)

Comment: I edited the comment, so read it again:)

Comment: As much as I want to go into this rabbit hole of inequality systems, I'm certain they wouldn't give us a problem that is that detail oriented, I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the whole point of this question is to make us more aware of the structure of our proofs.. Also he has been dropping hints all weeks about circular arguments and proof structure so I guess it's his way of helping us..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch is that when it states that "there exists an $ \epsilon_0 > 0 $", this $ \epsilon_0 $ depends on $ x_1 $, it is $ \epsilon_0(x_1) $. But $ x_1 $ was chosen based on $ \delta_1 $ which in turn was defined based on the choice of $ \epsilon_0 $. So the first $ \epsilon_0 $ and the second are not the same positive number!

The second $ \epsilon_0 $ is equal to $ \epsilon_0 = \epsilon_0 (x_1(\delta_1(\epsilon_0))) $

Comment: i don't see how $\epsilon_0$ is dependent. there is no statement "there exists an ϵ0>0" so $\epsilon_0$ can be replaced with any positive number

Comment: That is basically the difference between "for all" and "there exists". There exists $ \epsilon $ implies that this number is specific.